# Powershell | Excel | Insert whitespace

Tags: excel, powershell, whitespace

How to insert white space in excel cell? I am trying to user following code, but while writing to excel, it automatically trims the space.

```
$test = "122332323" + "        "
$ws.Cells.Item(5,1) = $test
```

I even tried `PadRight` but it also trims spaces while writing to excel.

Comment: It is probably getting formatted as a number... Two options come to mind, worth trying - Set the format of the cell first, and then set the value OR put a single quote before the number.

Comment: Could you please help how to set format of cell via powershell?

Comment: Have you tried this? $test = "'122332323        "  I added a single quote to the front and removed the + concatenation. That's not necessary in PowerShell.  I believe the single quote might do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

It's a cell format problem, define a 'text' type numberformat for the cell like this...

```
$test = "122332323" + "        "
$cell = $ws.Cells.Item(5,1)
$cell.NumberFormat = '@'
$cell.Value2 = $test
```